# access 2010 data in table is duplicating in reports. What do I need to check?

Tags: ms-access, vba

access 2010 data in table is duplicating in reports. I have 2 tables in this database related by SSN and Case Type. What do I need to check?

Comment: It would be helpful is you show the recordsource for the report. Assuming it is a query -- and you have joined the tables -- run your sql in the query designer and see where the issue lies.

Comment: There's something wrong with your joins, or you need to use DISTINCTROW